# Redirect all files in a subfolder with htaccess 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i've bunch of old urls, like these:

```
www.example.it/modules/prestapress/content.php?id=48
www.example.it/modules/prestapress/content.php?id=47
www.example.it/modules/prestapress/content.php?id=46
```

i wish to rewrite this urls to get the IDs and redirect to these urls:

```
www.example.com/it/blog/48
www.example.com/it/blog/47
www.example.com/it/blog/46
```

So, the site will change from .it to .com and, i need one rule to redirects all old articles blog to new articles urls (by IDs).

Here the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.it [NC]
RewriteRule ^modules/prestapress/content.php$ http://example.com/it/blog/%1? [R=301,L]
```

but in this way if i try to access:

```
example.it/modules/prestapress/content.php?id=48
```

it redirects to

```
example.com/it/blog/
```

without mantaining the ID.

CORRECT THE PROBLEM ! The proposal of @hjpotter92 was correct, but FIGHTS VS this other rule that i have, here the summary:

```
RewriteEngine On

#For redirecting urls blog

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.it [NC]
RewriteRule ^modules/prestapress/content.php$ http://example.com/it/blog/%1-? [R=301,L]

#FOR REDIRECT .IT to .COM for all others urls

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So the problem was 2 sites, i must redirect .it to .com , because .com have the same structure of .it, so with this rule i solved:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The only thing that change is the article's blog structure, and for that we have this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.it [NC]
RewriteRule ^modules/prestapress/content.php$ http://example.com/it/blog/%1-? [R=301,L]
```

but in this way the redirects of urls blog doesn't works !

FINALLY SOLVED, THE ORIGINAL RULE WAS NOT CORRECT, TO WORKS PERFECTLY HERE THE SOLUTION:

```
RewriteEngine On

#For redirecting urls blog

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=(\d+) [NC]
##WRONG RULE## RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.it [NC]
RewriteRule ^modules/prestapress/content.php$ http://example.com/it/blog/%1-? [R=301,L]

#FOR REDIRECT .IT to .COM for all others urls

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Didn't you want to move from `.it` to `.com`?

Comment: Yea! sorry i just edited again, was a mistake.

Comment: There are no other rewrite rules inside `blog`? Does it redirect you to `example.com/blog/` or `example.com/it/blog/ `?

Comment: Last one. (was another my mistake, now i edited correctly. Sorry again mate, i'm totally out of head :( No other rules in .htaccess

Comment: @hjpotter92: hi ! i'm so grateful if you could help me because i'm again at the same point :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.it [NC]
RewriteRule ^modules/prestapress/content.php$ http://www.new-site.com/blog/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Do use `%1?` to remove the query string from redirected URL.

Comment: Doesn't works ! Also i can't understand this RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=(\d+) [NC]

Comment: @Wrs-evotechRacingParts `%{QUERY_STRING}` is to match the `?id=` part of URL.

Comment: thanks for explanation of %{QUERY_STRING} :). Yea mod_rewrite is enabled ! No other rules in .htaccess. the redirect works if i digit: www.site.it/modules/prestapress but not if i tried to redirect an article !

Comment: Sorry ! was a mistake of WWW, because our site doesn't have WWW. So the rules works half: now the url redirected is: `http://www.site.c om/it/blog/?id=24` we're near the solution ! We must simply remove that `?id=` we need only the number of id !

Comment: i used `%1?` to remove the query string, but in this way also the ID is removed ! i need only the ID !

Comment: @Wrs-evotechRacingParts If the ID is integer, it will not be removed. You have some other rules for the new domain?

Comment: In that way it redirects to site.com/blog/ without mantain ID. Yes, here the other rules (added automatically by the module) `#propack - not remove this comment 
RewriteRule ^(.*)blog/category/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ /modules/propack/blockblog-category.php?category_id=$2 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)blog/post/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ /modules/propack/blockblog-post.php?post_id=$2 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)blog/categories/?$ /modules/propack/blockblog-categories.php [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)blog/?$ /modules/propack/blockblog-all-posts.php [QSA,L] 
#propack`

Comment: Using this `RewriteRule ^modules/prestapress/content.php$ http://site.c om/it/blog/%?` the ID remains but i've this url: `site.com/it/blog/%25` so i must removed that percent sign

Comment: Also removing the other rules doesn't works.. so i think it's an error of rules , because it doesn't works on an empty htaccess !

Comment: @Wrs-evotechRacingParts Put the current htaccess on old old site, new site; the url you are accessing and the url you're redirected to; all in the question itself. It is really cumbersome to read the code as comments here.

Comment: can't understand what you're saying. I told you that also removed all the other rules, you're solution doesn't works... here the entire .htaccess with only your rules : http://pastebin.com/xbHsSW6K

Comment: @Wrs-evotechRacingParts [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29486138/edit) your question; include the information as I said in comment above.

Comment: ok ! i just edited the original post with more information and with your code :) hope to solve :(